# Google App Engine python37 is ignoring entrypoint

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Since yesterday GAE is ignoring my `entrypoint` in the `app.yaml`

My `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python37

entrypoint: gunicorn -k eventlet -b :$PORT main:app
```

Leads to the following log output:

```
2019-04-24 07:39:58 default[20190423t203005]  [2019-04-24 07:39:58 +0000] [8] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-04-24 07:39:58 default[20190423t203005]  [2019-04-24 07:39:58 +0000] [8] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (8)
2019-04-24 07:39:58 default[20190423t203005]  [2019-04-24 07:39:58 +0000] [8] [INFO] Using worker: threads
```

But the worker should be `eventlet` not `threads`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an issue with Google App Engine as far as we can tell. Configured entrypoint is being ignored. Incident started yesterday. Our best guess is it's caused by an update to the process by which configuring the gvisor container's entrypoint happens during deploy (may be either App Engine or gVisor broke it).

If you change your logs to show all logs:

[image: Click the dropdown called 'stderr,appengine.google...' and select 'All Logs']

you'll see the execution entry point will always be:

```
Running /bin/sh /bin/sh -c exec gunicorn main:app --workers 1 -c /config/gunicorn.py
```

We're in the process of filing a ticket. If you can, you should do the same.

Comment: There is already an open issue here FYI: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131210363

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the link. :)

Comment: This is currently being addressed and should be resolved shortly.